# How to get paired data.table of upper or below triangle in grid square?

Tags: r, data.table

I have three data.table where each need to be paired one another in square grid. I want to only walk on the pair of upper / below triangle of grid square. I bet this is bit of straightforward in other programming language like java, but I don't know how to make it in R. Does anyone know of any trick of doing this easily?

## data

```
mylist <- list(
  a <- data.table(
  start=seq(1, by=9, len=10), stop=seq(6, by=9, len=10),
  ID=letters[seq(1:10)], score=sample(1:25, 10, replace = FALSE)),
  b <- data.table(
    start=seq(2, by=11, len=10), stop=seq(8, by=11, len=10),
    ID=letters[seq(1:10)], score=sample(1:25, 10, replace = FALSE)),
  c <- data.table(
    start=seq(4, by=11, len=10), stop=seq(9, by=11, len=10),
    ID=letters[seq(1:10)], score=sample(1:25, 10, replace = FALSE))
)
```

## all possible pair in square grid (I did manually):

```
grid <- matrix((a,a), (a,b), (a,c),
               (b,a), (b,b), (b,c),
               (c,a), (c,b), (c,c),3,3)
```

I couldn't find proper method to create grid object efficiently, so I roughly pin out the grid by manually.

## desired output:

grid object could be matrix or some other representation. This is scratch code where imagine that get.ovlp return grid representation that mentioned above, but overlapped pairs were repeated. my objective is remove these repeated pair by only only walk on upper/below triangle of squre grid

```
library(data.table)
mylist <- list(a,b,c)
get.ovlp <- function(set, idx=1L) {
  que <- set[[idx]]
  supp <- lapply(set[-idx], function(ele_) {
    ans <- data.table::foverlaps(que, ele_)
  })
  return(supp)
}
```

get.ovlp function is just toy example that how repeated paired overlap happens like grid object represented.

I only walk on pair for upper/below triangle (including diagonal) from above square grid, then use foverlaps function from data.table package. Can anyone propose possible ideas to solve this problem efficiently? Thanks a lot

Comment: The line to build the `grid` object is not valid and produces an error. What do you mean by `let each data.table as pair`? The desired output is not clear to me

Comment: @nicola: I couldn't find proper method to build proper grid object efficiently. Therefore, I just manually represent how my grid object are.

Comment: `a`, `b` and `c` are `data.table`s. You want a 3x3 matrix in which each element contains two `data.table`s? Why you want this? You say that you want to use `foverlaps`. Can you explain how? Can you show the desired output of just an element of your `grid`?

Comment: @nicola: I add my further comment on my post. But, the function that I coded is just an example that explain how I got grid object that I mentioned above. All data and possible desired output are simulated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to apply a function to pairs of elements found in `mylist`, e.g. `("a", "b")`. You could for example do this (I use `merge` as an example for the function):

```
require(data.table)

# your data (I named the elements a, b, and c)
mylist <- list(a = data.table(start=seq(1, by=9, len=10), stop=seq(6, by=9, len=10),
                              ID=letters[seq(1:10)], score=sample(1:25, 10, replace = FALSE)),
               b = data.table(start=seq(2, by=11, len=10), stop=seq(8, by=11, len=10),
                              ID=letters[seq(1:10)], score=sample(1:25, 10, replace = FALSE)),
               c = data.table(start=seq(4, by=11, len=10), stop=seq(9, by=11, len=10),
                              ID=letters[seq(1:10)], score=sample(1:25, 10, replace = FALSE)))


# build pairs on upper triangle
# utilise fact that >= is meaningful for characters
dt_idx = CJ(i = names(mylist), j = names(mylist))[j >= i]

# apply function (here merge) by i, j:
dt_idx[,
       j = merge(x = mylist[[i]], y = mylist[[j]], by = c('start', 'stop', 'ID')),
       by = list(i, j)]
```

**Note:**
In case the `>=` operation on the list names isn't "meaningful" anymore (because the names are not ordered and/or more complicated) you can always use an `integer` index, then apply the same logic...

```
dt_idx = CJ(i = seq.int(length(mylist)), j = seq.int(length(mylist)))[j >= i]
```

Comment: point is grid object that I mentioned above contain repeated paired, let's imagine, for example, setdiff(a,b) are same as setdiff(b,a), which are placed on the grid square, so only walk on upper/below triangle of grid square, non repeated paired happen in new grid.

Comment: yes, `dt_idx` doesn't include those "duplicates" (when you don't consider order)

Comment: I wonder if extend same logic to other object like data.frame, then CJ function must have corresponding alternative, right?

Comment: do you mean a `data.frame` alterantive for `data.table::CJ`? have a look at  `?expand.grid`